# Conflict between babel spanish and custom verbatim

Tags: babel, verbatim, spanish

I have a custom verbatim environment and use Spanish option in `babel`.

The code below, instead of printing `"command"` in verbatim, replaces `"c` with `ç`. Changes also occur with every vocal used after `"`, as well as `y`. Using `"r` gives a compilation error:

```
Bad character code (-1). \end{frame}
```

Other letters seem to offer no problem at all.

If I remove the `babel` package, problem disappears. Similarly, if do not use my redefined environment, problem disappears. That's as far as I could get with my debugging. Can't figure out the source of the problem. Seems to be some incompatibility between `\semiverbatim` and Spanish. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass{beamer}     
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\renewenvironment{verbatim}
{\semiverbatim\color{red}}
{\endsemiverbatim}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

        \begin{verbatim}
            "command"
        \end{verbatim}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try adding `shorthands=off` to the options of the `babel` package.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks! Solved. Why is this problematic with my redefined environment?

Comment: @leandriis For some reason, this command makes the manual three dots "..." inside math environment invisible.

Comment: Manual three dots is being re-defined inside `textspanish`. Use `\ldots` (`$t \ldots R$`) for spacing, or switch language (`${\selectlanguage{english}...}$`), with, in the latter example, the language being added to `babel` options: `\usepackage[english,spanish,`... Only a workaround, though.

Comment: @Cicada A workaround indeed, but now not an issue because the best option wasn't `shorthands=off` but `es-noshorthands`, as suggested in documentation. No dots problems here.

Comment: @leandriis Found a better solution which does not mess up with other commands. See update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `es-noshorthands` to the options of the babel package.

PD: previous version suggested to use `shorthand=off` in the options *(leandriis comment)*. This introduces some problems with commas inside mathematical formulas (as used in Spanish), as well as the manual three dots (...). Essentially, they disappear. The new suggestion has none of this problems, and is indeed the one suggested in the [official](https://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/spanish/spanish.pdf) babel-spanish package documentation.

Comment: +1: Thanks for the follow-up after such a long time!